# Find and exec using pulled variable

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, find

So far I have a simple batch script that moves *.mkv files from their source folders to a folder called "Movies". Now I would like FileBot to rename them using the 'find' command, since it (filebot) doesn't seem to support regular expressions. How would I have bash pull a file-name-variable (not sure if this is a thing haha) and use it in find -exec "$FILENAME" kind of pattern?

Here is what I have (pseudo is commented out), I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this. But hey, I'm a python coder NOT a bash scripter!

```
mkdir "Movies"
find "Complete/" -iname "*.mkv" -exec mv {} "Movies" \;
#find "Movies/" -iname "*.mkv" -exec filebot -rename "$iname" --db themoviedb"
```

I need the mv and filebot commands to execute separately as eventually more commands will be called between them.

Comment: How do you want to rename? It it just to lowercase the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for the second line, mv takes wildcards too, so you can simply use

> mv Complete/*.mkv Movies

Is it possible that filebot also takes wildcards? i.e. filebot Movies/*.mkv? Otherwise, instead of "$iname", you just want {} again. As you probably know, {} substitutes for the name of the file found, which is the same as *.mkv here.  Hence,

> find "Movies/" -iname "*.mkv" -execdir filebot -rename {} --db themoviedb \;

N.B. use -execdir instead of -exec for security reasons. From the man page:

> There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.
>
> -execdir command {} +
>
> Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.  This a much more secure  method
>                 for  invoking  commands,  as  it  avoids  race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files.

Comment: To clarify, it isn't that mv takes wildcards. The shell expands the patterns *before* it hands the arguments to mv. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: Ah nice catch. Hence, I imagine `filebot -rename Movies/*.mkv --db themoviedb` should work.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I am using 'find' as the *.mkv files are located in subdirectories. Is there an option to use wildcards with subdirectories? The files can be located at any level..

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't think you can use wildcards directly for subdirectories, because it's not like they can substitute for "/" for example. I agree with using `find` in this case then. Good luck with your script!